# Select where has two results or more

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table with these records:

```
id      viagem_id   erro    mensagem
9350    0000038037  false   Documento PAT 75928 foi gravado 2017-10-26 09:06:31
9349    0000038037  true    DOcumento SD 0000508183 item 000010 foi cancelado: Motivo RECUSA FINANCEIRA 2017-10-26 08:59:48
```

I want to have as result records that trip has one or more result, but count is not working with postgres

```
select
    h.viagem_id,
    count(viagem_id),
    h.mensagem
from
    sap.hist_rec_viagem h 
where
    h.horario between '25/10/2017' and '27/10/2017'
group by
    h.viagem_id, mensagem
having
    count(viagem_id) > 1
order by
    viagem_id
```

Comment: Can you add `actual result` and `expected result`

Comment: _"count is not working"_ is not a problem description. Aggregate functions don't tend to seek employment. What did you want it to do, and what did it do instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count `trips`, then leave `mensagem` out of the query:

```
select h.viagem_id, count(viagem_id)
from sap.hist_rec_viagem h 
where h.horario between '2017-10-25' and '2017-10-27'
group by h.viagem_id
having count(viagem_id) > 1
order by viagem_id;
```

If you want all the detail in the original rows, then use window functions:

```
select h.*
from (select h.*, count(*) over (partition by viagem_id) as cnt
      from sap.hist_rec_viagem h 
      where h.horario between '2017-10-25' and '2017-10-27'
     ) h
where cnt > 1
order by viagem_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you search duplicate on same `viagem_id` use a `CTE` expression (similar to nested query, but more elegant) to find duplicate key and after join with original table to select detail :

```
with duplicate_viagem_id as
    select
        viagem_id,
        count(*) as nb
    from
        sap.hist_rec_viagem h 
    where
        h.horario between '25/10/2017' and '27/10/2017'
    group by
        h.viagem_id
    having
        count(*) > 1
),
select
     h.viagem_id,
     d.nb,
     h.mensagem
from
     sap.hist_rec_viagem h inner join duplicate_viagem_id d on 
        h.viagem_id=d.viagem_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL:

```
select
    co.viagem_id,
    co.count,
    ca.mensagem
from
    (
        select
            h.viagem_id,
            count( viagem_id )
        from
            sap.hist_rec_viagem h
        where
            h.horario between '25/10/2017' and '27/10/2017'
        group by
            h.viagem_id
        having
            count( viagem_id )> 1
    ) co inner join(
        select
            viagem_id,
            mensagem
        from
            sap.hist_rec_viagem
    ) ca on
    (
        ca.viagem_id = co.viagem_id
    )
order by
    viagem_id
```